# find files with same names in directory

Tags: shell

I was wondering in case I could do the following, better than what I have.

Objective: Identify files with the same name in the directory tree. I do not have any knowledge if there would be any duplicate file or the location/name of such files.

Expected output: List the files with the location.

Input provided: path of top directory for search.

My algorithm:

1.list all file in the target directory (I have used find -name ".")

2.List1: sort the file names

3.List2: Uniquify files names

4.Diff lists from step 2 & 3 to get the repeated file

5.extract the location.

```
Sample Directory:
temp/
|-- d1
|   |-- d2
|   |   `-- f3
|   |-- d3
|   |   `-- f3
|   |-- f1
|   `-- f2
`-- d4
    |-- d5
    |   |-- f2
    |   `-- f6
    |-- f4
    `-- f5


> find temp/ -type f -follow -print | sed 's;.*/;;' | sort -u > ~/tmp/12
> find temp/ -type f -follow -print | sed 's;.*/;;' | sort -n > ~/tmp/11

> diff ~/tmp/11 ~/tmp/12
3,4d2
< f2
< f3

> find temp/ -name f2
temp/d1/f2
temp/d4/d5/f2

> find temp/ -name f3
temp/d1/d2/f3
temp/d1/d3/f3
```

I want to simplify this process. Any help would be appriciated. Please let me know in case you need further details.

Comment: You may want to add `uniq -d` following (or instead of) your sort that may help you match only duplicates. You may also want to look at the linux `tree` command for formatted output you show. There you may be able to run `tree` on `dir1` `dir2` writing the output to **tmp** and then use grep to locate duplicates. Just a thought for a different approach. What you have doesn't look like a bad start.

Comment: I am looking for a method where I could avoid tmp files if possible, as the target directory may not have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this is a solution that I identified fitting my needs and may help you:
Your comments are welcome.

```
set idirectory = `echo $* | awk '{print $1}'`
if ( -d $idirectory ) then  
    foreach xxx (`find $idirectory -type f -follow -print | sed 's;.*/;;' | sort -n | uniq -d`)
        echo "Multiple files found for " $xxx
        find $idirectory -name $xxx
    end
endif
```